# Scenebuilder shows error after the installation

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

Installed scene builder for my JavaFX project, after the installation is completed it shows the following error,

[image: error message after the installation]

[image]

Version of scenebuilder: SceneBuilder-8.3.0.exe which is downloaded from http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/

I'm trying to integrate with Eclipse neon 4.6 and Java 1.8.0 version
with win 7 professional 64 bit OS

also,
I've tried providing the exe path from the windows-->preference but still no luck. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you try steps which specified in the link: https://deltadata.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/javafx-scene-builder-failed-to-create-jvm-fix/ . Hope it is useful.

Comment: @GltknBtn the link is improper I mean it contains double quotes at the end which is giving error as 404 : Page not found.
I've corrected the link as: 
https://deltadata.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/javafx-scene-builder-failed-to-create-jvm-fix/

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 I fixed it. thanks

Comment: @GltknBtn You are welcome :-)

Comment: @GltknBtn, I've already tried changing it to 512 m but no luck

Comment: When I try running the executable jar C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\app\dist.jar , it launches the scene builder but when I try opening the fxml file from the eclipse it shows the same error

Comment: Can you check the scene builder exe path in eclipse:  Preferences -> JavaFX -> set SceneBuilder executable = C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe

Comment: @GltknBtn, Tried it but same error, do you know the path of previous version build , may be some compatible issues

Comment: @user2459816, I have unistalled my 8.0.2 version and installed 8.3.0 (http://gluonhq.com/download/scene-builder-windows-x64/) and tried. It is working both in eclipse and as application exe. I have latest Jdk8 64bit. If you have time uninstall scenebuilder and jdk then delete their old directories. Later Install latest jdk8 and scenebuilder specified in link. Hope it works.

Comment: @GltknBtn, will give it a try and let you know

Comment: @GltknBtn, I've tried uninstalling and re-installing but still the same error pop's up, any other suggestions

Comment: @user2459816, Maybe new scenebuilder version on Eclipse Neon cause it.  Can you download and install  scenebuilder 2.0 Windows 32/64 bit (msi) old version in this link( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html) hope it works.

Comment: @GltknBtn, I tried this already but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to uninstall and reinstall the scene builder. Also, check the compatibility of Java version and scene builder. If after reinstalling again you face the issue then try to search solutions for

```
ERROR: failed to launch jvm
```

Since, what I feel is your JVM is failing so I think you need to resolve that first.

Comment: I've also tried uninstalling and re-installing it but no luck

Comment: if you can provide the earlier version download link for scene builder it will be grateful .. I tried to download the previous versions but couldn't able to get it

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to add this line `app.classpath=.;dist.jar` in the "../app/SceneBuilder.cfg" file.